# How can I provide variables.scss to each .scss file when bundling with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

This is my current project directory structure, as I couldn't think of a better way of organizing for the use case that every component has it's own `.scss` file, however, the entire app are fed themes which include a global `variables.scss` file. Currently, I'm importing the `variables.scss` file at the top of every component's `.scss` file and I'm wondering what the best practices are for this sort of workflow.

```
/ app
  / components
     / Navigation
       - Navigation.js
       - Navigation.scss
/ styles
  - globals.scss
  - variables.scss
  - main.scss
```

My main.scss file basically `@import` all `.scss` in its directory (e.g. `variables.scss`, `globals.scss`, etc.), however, I need to the following to have access to variables inside of each component:

```
 // Navigation.scss
 @import '../../styles/variables.scss

 .class { ... }
```

I understand I could also import all component `.scss` files inside of the `main.scss` directory but that defeats the purpose of having css modules and being able to import them at component level for name spacing, etc.

Comment: I doubt there is a way; a quick look in the [SASS options](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options) does not reveal something along these lines. You could at least make your life a bit easier by including the folder of `variables.scss` to the `includePaths` of the SASS loader and write `@import "variables.scss"` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I don't recommend it.

**Dependencies**

Every component has it's dependencies. You have to require several dependencies in each Sass (ES6/React.js) module. That's how Webpack resolves dependencies.

I recommend add an resolve path to Webpack / Sass config and import the variables file in each Sass module.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but do you mean to inject in each file an import for variables.scss??